# Saving the input image from Face detection as a file? [Flutter + Google ML Kit Face Detection]

Tags: flutter, face-detection, google-mlkit

is it possible to save the processed image as a File?

Here is what I'm trying to do, our app have a KYC (Know your customer) and we implemented the
face detection to make the users do several poses. What I want is to save them as an image file and upload it on the database

Example Scenario:
App ask the user to smile > The user smiled > save the image.

Here is what I have right now:

Where the app checks if the user smiled

```
if (faces.isNotEmpty) {
  if (inputImage.inputImageData?.size != null &&
      inputImage.inputImageData?.imageRotation != null) {
    if (faces[0].smilingProbability! > 0.85) {
      await _getImg();
    }
  }
}
```

Then I call a Function to stop image stream then take a picture (this works but on some physical device it crashes) but if I dont stop the image stream then called the takePicture() right-away it just crashes all the time.

```
  _getImg() async {
setState(() {
  globalBusy = true;
});
await _controller.stopImageStream();
var img = await _controller.takePicture();
VerificationVarHandler.livelinesImgsPaths.add(img.path);
}
```

As you can see it's not the best way at least for me I think, so maybe I can use the
inputImage from the _processCameraImage() because it has a byte? then I can pass that bytes to a decoder and save it locally when I trigger a function?

Or maybe better yet there is more elegant way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

From my R&D, i found out that the InputImage used is of format nv21(1 plane) and we need to convert it to yuv420 (3 planes)

Follow this thread for more details: https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/issues/535

```
//Import the Image package
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imglib;


imglib.Image decodeYUV420SP(
    InputImage image,
  ) {
    final width = image.metadata!.size.width.toInt();
    final height = image.metadata!.size.height.toInt();

    Uint8List yuv420sp = image.bytes!;
    //int total = width * height;
    //Uint8List rgb = Uint8List(total);
    var outImg =
        imglib.Image(width: width, height: height); // default numChannels is 3

    final int frameSize = width * height;

    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
      int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
        int y = (0xff & yuv420sp[yp]) - 16;
        if (y < 0) y = 0;
        if ((i & 1) == 0) {
          v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
          u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
        }
        int y1192 = 1192 * y;
        int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
        int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
        int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

        if (r < 0)
          r = 0;
        else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
        if (g < 0)
          g = 0;
        else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
        if (b < 0)
          b = 0;
        else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

        // outImg.setPixelRgb(i, j, ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) >> 16,
        //     ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) >> 8, b & 0xff);
        outImg.setPixelRgb(i, j, ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) >> 16,
            ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) >> 8, (b >> 10) & 0xff);

        /*rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 |
            ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) |
            ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) |
            ((b >> 10) & 0xff);*/
      }
    }

    //Rotate Image 90 degree to left
    outImg = imglib.copyRotate(outImg, angle: -90);

    return outImg;
  }

// Call the function & Decode the image
final imglib.Image yuvdecodedImage = decodeYUV420SP(inputImage);
print('yuvdecodedImage: $yuvdecodedImage');
final image = Image.memory(imglib.encodeJpg(yuvdecodedImage));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can check out this gfg article - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/face-detection-in-flutter-using-firebase-ml-kit/

Learn flutter in easiest way - https://auth.geeksforgeeks.org/user/ms471841/articles

Comment: I think you miss understood me, I don't have a problem with flutter or the face detection in general, What I'm asking is just the part where the processed image bytes can be turned into an actual image file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).